# How can i filter records from proxy in VUE3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am using `ref()` to store data from firebase. But when I am trying to filter and get the single record. It looks something like the below. But it is not supposed to. I should return a single object. Below is my code, Please guide me where i am wrong.

[image]

```
const topicalData = ref<Array<any>>()
const topicalDataLength = ref(0)
const questions = ref()

topical.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  topicalData.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data()
    const id = doc.id
    return { id, ...data }
  })
  topicalDataLength.value = topicalData.value.length
})

const loadQuestions = (id: string) => {
  questions.value = topicalData.value?.map((data) => {
    return data.id == id ? data : false
  })
  console.log(questions.value)
  // questionTopical.value = true
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I am assuming function **loadQuestions**  is intended to return a single object. If that's the case, you should use `.find()` rather than `.map()`

Comment: Why is it called `questions` if you expect a single question? Whether it's a proxy or not isn't relevant. A proxy is a way Vue handles object reactivity and behaves the same as an object behind it most times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 3, `ref()` performs a deep reactive operation if you pass it a non-primitive value. So, in your case the array as well as each nested object will be recursively wrapped into proxies.
If you don't want reactivity inside nested objects of your array, use `shallowRef()` instead. Check official docs for more details- https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref